# MongoDB multiple async queries return unordered result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have an array of Courses [course1, course2, ..., courseN]. Each course has a Hero UUID, which matches the UUID of an object in another collection.

```
// This is actually another db query but imagine it's an array

var courses = [{
    "courseName": "Sample course name 1",
    "hero": "a3f6f088-7b04-45e8-8d3b-d50c2d5b3a2d"
}, {
    "courseName": "Sample course name 2",
    "hero": "1b46227a-c496-43d2-be8e-1b0fa07cc94e"
}, {
    "courseName": "Sample course name 3",
    "hero": "c3bae6bf-2553-473a-9f30-f5c58c4fd608"
}];
```

I need to iterate over all courses, get the hero uuid and do a query to the Heroes collection then when the query is complete add the hero information to the course object.

The problem is that all queries are fired so rapidly that MongoDB returns them in arbitrary order. It receives all 3 hero uuids in order but it will sometimes return the third one before the first one, etc. Is there a way for one query to complete then do the other one, etc.?

What I am doing right now is:

```
var newCourses = courses;
var counter = 0;

courses.forEach(function (course) {
    var courseHeroUuid = course.hero;
    // This function does the query by uuid and returns the doc
    getHeroByUuid(courseHeroUuid, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }

        // Replace the hero UUID with the hero document itself
        newCourses[counter].hero = result[0];

        if (++counter == courses.length) {
            next(null, newCourses);
        }
    }
});
```

This is a function inside an async.waterfall array, this is why I track the counter and call next() to go on. I know I can use async.each for the iteration, I tried it didn't help out.
This is the query I am doing.

```
function getHeroByUuid(heroUuid, callback) {
    Hero.find({uuid: heroUuid}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }

        callback(null, result);
    })
}
```

This happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVyTh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but I figured it out. What I needed was right under my nose.

I ended up using the `async.whilst()` function, documentation is [right here](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback) and does exactly what I need - execute the next iteration of the loop after the result from the previous one is returned.

My code now looks like this:

```
var newCourses = courses;
var courseItemsLength = courses.length;
var counter = 0;

async.whilst(
    function () {
        return counter < courseItemsLength;
}, function (callback) {
    var heroUuid = allCourses[counter].hero;

    getHeroByUuid(heroUuid, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }

        newCourses[counter].hero = result.name;

        counter++;
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }

        callback();
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    }

    next(null, newCourses);
});
```